# DevExpress Refreshing datagridview in vb.net not working

Tags: vb.net, datagridview, devexpress, vb.net-2010

DevExpress Refreshing datagridview in vb.net not working.

I load one table from my database to datagridview and it display all the data

**Problem** - When I load another table from database to datagridview, It wasn't working. Only the first table will display its data while the second table won't display any data to datagridview.

Comment: And what doesn't work? I can assume that your second table has different columns (field names). So, you need to correct existing column field names

Comment: What happens? Empty rows or something else?

Comment: Can you post your code so I can see exactly which objects/controls are in play?

Comment: Yes @Gosha_Fighten. I have different columns (field names) in my next table. How can I change the column names base on my new table from database?

Comment: I got an empty rows @MarkoJuvančič. And the column names don't change. I still got the 1st table column headers.

Comment: Have you manually created these columns in the GridView?? If yes then it will not work. If you are trying to populate columns and data from the data source then check the PopulateColumns method. first set data source to null then again assign new data source to the control. Hope this help.

Comment: No @NiranjanKala. My columns in the Gridview are based on database. For example, I fetch the table A with (columnA,columnB,columnC) then after, I fetch table B with (columnD,columnE,columnF)(different table column header in the first table) then after that only the column header of table A will display while the table B column won't display in GridView.

Answer (score 0):

After you assign a new data source to the grid, call the [GridView.PopulateColumns](https://documentation.devexpress.com/#WindowsForms/DevExpressXtraGridViewsBaseColumnView_PopulateColumnstopic%28O2YgHA%29) method to re-generate columns:

```
gridControl1.DataSource = secondDataTable;
GridView gv = (GridView)gridControl1.FocusedView;
gv.PopulateColumns(secondDataTable);
```

Comment: This code doesn't help me. I still got no solutions for this. This is my code:


dgvMain.DataSource = clsVendors2.getVendorsStatus("2")

***I should change the column header of datagridview.

Comment: @VincentBryanF.Calija
What object does clsVendors2.getVendorsStatus("2") return? DataTable, List, something else?

Comment: The data that I'm going to fetch from the database.

Comment: @VincentBryanF.Calija What type of data? DataTable, List, etc.

Comment: @VincentBryanF.Calija Hm, DataGridView is a control. How can it be a data source for the Grid? Probably, you need to use its data source? Like gridControl1.DataSource = dataGridView1.DataSource?

Comment: Thnx for ur help. Problem already solved. We just need to replace our datagridview with the vb.net datagridview because datagridview in devexpress don't change column.

Comment: @VincentBryanF.Calija
I believe DevExpress Grid control should do this. Obvious, it's a basic functionality. If the DevExpress Grid control still does not work, I'd suggest you contact DevExpress directly via their Support Center.

Answer (score 0):

There are two possible reasons for this kind of behavior:

---

1. The columns are different in the second datatable.

The symptom of this is: you see as many empty row in the grid as there are rows in the second datatable.

Cause: `Gridcontrol` (gridview to be precise) already has `Columns` property and doesn't find matching pairs.

Solution: Call `GridControl.PopulateColumns()` after loading the second datatable. This will recreate `Colums` property.

---

2. Gridview doesn't realize that the underlying datasource has been changed.

Symptom: you see old values.

Solution: Call `GridView.Refresh()`

---

As far as I can see from your comments, you have the former issue. 
So, do something in this manner:

```
gridControl.DataSource = myFirstDataTable();

/* some other code*/ 

gridControl.DataSource = mySecondDataTable();
(gridControl.MainView as ColumnView).PopulateColumns()
```